# qt creator project change directory

Tags: c++, c++11, mercurial, qt-creator, scons

I want to redeploy an existing application developed in **C++**, using **Fltk** toolkit, **Clam** compiler and **make** files. I want to use now **Qt Creator** to manage the project.
I created a new project, importing the application files in Qt, with a new **Mercurial** repository, and I have now the set of files used by my project, which compiles and runs finely.
But the Qt project files are within my src directory and I'd like to put them, with Mercurial repo, outside, in a specific build dir.
How can I relocate the project files and **Mercurial** repo? I've seen nothing in Qt wizards to do that. What files and paths do I change? How, eventually, can I use **Scons** instead of make?

Answer (score 0):

SCons has a toolset for `QT` that you can load when creating the Environment, as follows:

```
env = Environment(tools = ['qt'])
```

There is a more advanced qt toolset called `qt4`, that can be downloaded separately, [here](http://scons.org/wiki/Qt4Tool).

Once you load this toolset, you can then use the `Moc()`, `Uic()`, and related Construction Variables as mention in the [SCons man page](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html).

As for how to specify the location of the build files, there are plenty of other Questions/Answers in Stack Overflow that address this.